# SQL : Fetching new data by date from mysql without iterating in program

Tags: mysql

I have a table called student with the structure below. the table represents student visitors to a library.

```
Id Name   Date          StudentId
1  John   2010-01-09      3
2  Matt   2010-01-10      5
3  Jane   2010-02-10      8
4  John   2010-02-10      3
5  Matt   2010-02-11      5
6  Jane   2010-02-11      8
7  Bob    2010-02-12      9
8  Tom    2010-02-12      10
9  Sam    2010-02-12      11
10 Jane   2010-02-12      8
```

I am running a query to fetch New visitors everyday. New visitors are visitors who have never visited the library before that date.The query I am using is as below.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM student 
  WHERE DATE(Date) = :date
  AND Name NOT IN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM student WHERE DATE(Date) < :date);
```

I am currently iterating over each date in the table in my program and then using the query above to fetch me New visitors everyday. This works fine but was wondering if it is possible to fetch all values in a single query without iterating in the program? what is more optimal?

the output I am expecting is as below:

```
Date         Count of New Visitors
2010-01-09       1
2010-01-10       2
2010-01-11       0
2010-01-12       3
```

please note that the below query that I have tried will not fetch the correct result

```
SELECT Date, Count(*) FROM student 
  WHERE DATE(Date) BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate
  AND Name NOT IN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM student WHERE DATE(Date) < :startdate)  GROUP BY Date;
```

The result(which is incorrect and what I am not looking for ) I will get from the above query for startdate = 2010-01-09 and enddate = 2010-01-12 is below:

```
Date         Count of New Visitors
2010-01-09       1
2010-01-10       3
2010-01-11       2
2010-01-12       4
```

Comment: `student` might not be the best name for a table that records `visitors`

Comment: this is just a representation of the actual table where the actual table is completely different. The structure however is similar

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your test output. I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select u1.date,
(select count(*)
 from users u2 
 where u2.date = u1.date 
 and u2.studentid not in(select studentid from users u3 where u3.date < u2.date)) c
from users u1
group by u1.date
```

Comment: What is the error you  are referring to ? I believe the output is correct.